# Need help understanding example

Tags: python

apologies for the vague nature of my question, however I don't really know what to call the issue I'm having.  So, I found an example online that explains how to use the png module which I have managed to get working and can read in from a png file.  So I can read in the png file in the python interpreter as follows.  First you define in_file to be the png file of interest, then type

```
>>>r=png.Reader(file=in_file)
>>>r.read()
>>>l=list(_[2])
```

I don't really understand the last line, can anyone explain what this is doing?  I can see that somehow this associates the png data with the list `l` but am not really clear on the details.  What I actually want to do is include this in a python script, I tried copying this into my script but it fails at this line, returning

```
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

Again if anyone could explain what is happening and how this should be adapted such that it would work in a script that would be very helpful.

Comment: Where did you take this code from? Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: @Lix it's correct but will only work in the interpreter, not in scripts.

Answer (score 5):

In the interactive interpreter, `_` is the result of the last statement - in this case the return value of the `r.read()` call. This obviously won't work in scripts as it is only available in the python console. Simply assign the return value to some other variable and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help you understand the data coming out of r.read(). In your code above the variable '_' is not defined in a script (available in console as stated above). If you had reader_list[2] you would get the third entry in the list.

```
import png

r = png.Reader('png_file.png')
reader_list = list(r.read())
for element in reader_list :
    print(element)
```

Output:

```
997
520
<itertools.imap object at 0xb725aa8c>
{'bitdepth': 8, 'interlace': 0, 'planes': 4, 'greyscale': False, 'alpha': True, 'gamma': 0.45455, 'size': (997, 520)}
```

Also take a look at the documentation http://pythonhosted.org/pypng/index.html. Hope this helps.